# wget fails to download some images in a webpage

Tags: download, wget, mirroring

So when I tried to download [this webpage](https://www.inhaltsangabe.de/autoren/brecht/) with wget, the text and styling works well, but some images are missing. Upon further research, the files fail to download because the url wget tries to retrieve them from is invalid, as the console output suggests:

```
URL transformed to HTTPS due to an HSTS policy
--2021-07-13 21:53:51--  https://www.inhaltsangabe.de/autoren/%7B%7B%20data.avatar_url%20%7D%7D
Reusing existing connection to [www.inhaltsangabe.de]:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.inhaltsangabe.de/autoren/%7B%7B%20data.avatar_url%20%7D%7D/ [following]
--2021-07-13 21:53:52--  https://www.inhaltsangabe.de/autoren/%7B%7B%20data.avatar_url%20%7D%7D/
Reusing existing connection to [www.inhaltsangabe.de]:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-07-13 21:53:53 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

The actual image on the website is accessible and has the following url:

```
https://www.inhaltsangabe.de/wp-content/themes/yootheme/cache/brecht-276fafb8.jpeg
```

Other images work fine in the downloaded file. This seems to have something to do with url encoding, but I have no idea on how to solve this problem.

My command:

```
wget -p www.inhaltsangabe.de/autoren/brecht
```

(also please be gentle as this is my first question asked here)

Comment: For anyone else with this problem: It seems to be a problem with javascript, see [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/omf7cj/wget_fails_to_download_some_images_off_a_webpage/h5kjzat?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**404 Errors**

> This seems to have something to do with url encoding[.]

Decoding the encoded portions of the failing links reveals that the "paths" are actually variable names present in the document source (so e.g. `%7B%7B%20data.avatar_url%20%7D%7D` becomes `{{ data.avatar_url }}`). So that would likely be the reason for returning the `404` responses, not the encoding.

The leading `https://www.inhaltsangabe.de/autoren/` is probably (mis)applied by `wget` because each variable appears in an `<img>` tag `src` attribute:

*ex. {{ data.images.thumbnail.url }}*

```
<# if ( data.images.thumbnail ) { #>
      <img class="suggestion-post-thumbnail" src="{{ data.images.thumbnail.url }}" alt="{{ data.post_title }}">
      <# } #>
```

*ex. {{ data.avatar_url }}*

```
<# if ( data.avatar_url ) { #>
    <img class="suggestion-user-thumbnail" src="{{ data.avatar_url }}" alt="{{ data.display_name }}">
    <# } #>
```

---

**Missing JPEG**

> Other images work fine in the downloaded file.

Regarding `brecht-276fafb8.jpeg`, while admittedly a bit of an educated guess, it appears likely that `wget` is processing `<img>` tag `src` and `srcset` attributes in the document source, but not any `data-src` or `data-srcset` attributes. For example:

*ex. brecht-276fafb8.jpeg -> data-src, data-srcset (Fail!)*

`<img class="el-image uk-border-circle uk-box-shadow-small" alt="Bertolt Brecht" data-src="/wp-content/themes/yootheme/cache/brecht-276fafb8.jpeg" data-srcset="/wp-content/themes/yootheme/cache/brecht-276fafb8.jpeg 350w" data-sizes="(min-width: 350px) 350px" data-width="350" data-height="350" uk-img>`

*ex. bradbury.jpg ->src, srcset (Success!)*

`<img width="300" height="300" src="https://www.inhaltsangabe.de/dateien/bradbury-300x300.jpg" alt="Ray Bradbury" sizes="(min-width: 300px) 300px" srcset="https://www.inhaltsangabe.de/dateien/bradbury-300x300.jpg 300w, https://www.inhaltsangabe.de/dateien/bradbury-150x150.jpg 150w, https://www.inhaltsangabe.de/dateien/bradbury.jpg 400w"/>`

This makes sense as the `src` and `srcset` attributes likely affect the general presentation of the document (i.e. images to show), whereas `data-*` attributes are primarily aimed at scripting, etc. and don't have any presentational value on their own.

---

*As far as I am aware, at least in prior versions, custom attributes (e.g. `data-*`) were generally unsupported by `wget`. Regarding `src` and `scrset`, you can see them explicitly mentioned in the lists of attributes to process under `src/html-url.c` in the source code for `wget` ).*

---

> I have no idea on how to solve this problem.

Unfortunately, I am not aware of a good solution to this issue. My thought might be to do some manual post-processing on the given document source with something like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to extract any relevant links. But I am not sure if that could be considered a "good" or not.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I simply ignored the problem, as other sites work fine, but this seems to be a bug worth submitting to the wget creators.

Comment: Your welcome. I hope that report you submit gets some traction.